# PHP Fat Free Frame work Routing is not working

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /buildzone_admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

Above is my Htaccess Code for routing.

```
<?php

$main = require __DIR__ . '/lib/base.php';
$main->set('AUTOLOAD', 'inc/');

F3::set('CACHE', false);
F3::set('DEBUG', 3);
F3::set('UI', 'ui/'); 


$main->route('GET /', 'index');


$main->route('POST /show', 'Test->show');

$main->route('POST /loginCheck', 'BuildzoneAuth->authenticate');

F3::set('DB', new DB(
'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=sunkomen_buildzone', 
'123', '123'
    )
);


function index() 
{
    F3::set('modules', array(
    'apc' =>
    'Cache engine',
    'gd' =>
    'Graphics plugin',
    'hash' =>
    'Framework core',
    'imap' =>
    'Authentication',
    'json' =>
     'Various plugins',
     'ldap' =>
     'Authentication',
     'memcache' =>
     'Cache engine',
     'mongo' =>
     'M2 MongoDB mapper',
     'pcre' =>
     'Framework core',
     'pdo_mssql' =>
     'SQL handler, Axon ORM, Authentication',
     'pdo_mysql' =>
     'SQL handler, Axon ORM, Authentication',
     'pdo_pgsql' =>
     'SQL handler, Axon ORM, Authentication',
     'pdo_sqlite' =>
     'SQL handler, Axon ORM, Authentication',
     'session' =>
     'Framework core',
     'sockets' =>
     'Network plugin',
     'xcache' =>
     'Cache engine'
         )
     );
    echo Template::serve('index.htm');

 }

F3::run();
?>
```

Above is my php code.
Problem is when i try to access any file it's says 404 file not found.

example:

> domain.com/buildzone_admin/

then it's work FINE.

But

> domain.com/buidzone_admin/logincheck

then it's says 404 File not found and same for any kind of Method GET or POST. it's not working.

Please let me know what i m missing in this.

Comment: also check the class exists in lib/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes i have already define as a POST method.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/lcherone/Fat-Free-Framework-Basic-Layout

Comment: Check if "AllowOverride All" is set for your apache server host configuration ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you did not provide enough information for us.

However, in this case, because you said `domain.com/buildzone_admin/` worked, I think problem's come with your `.htaccess` file.

RewriteBase is only useful in situations where you can only put a .htaccess at the root of your site. Otherwise, you may be better off placing your different .htaccess files in different directories of your site and completely omitting the RewriteBase directive.

Let's take a look.

You set `RewriteBase /buildzone_admin/`. I think you are building a site in the `buildzone_admin` folder which is a sub folder of your main domain root. If it true, and your `.htaccess` file is in same location with your `index.php` file, you do not need to set `RewriteBase /buildzone_admin/`, but just `RewriteBase /`.

**So, its solution is change `RewriteBase /buildzone_admin/` to `RewriteBase /`.**

**Secondly**, to test your configuration, you should provide routes that be simpler before making them complex. E.g: GET->POST, function->handler string

`$main->route('GET /test1', function() {echo "test with function worked";});`

->open browser to access `domain.com/buildzone_admin/test1` then see if this work

`$main->route('GET /test2', 'Test->get');` with `get` method just echo another string.

->open browser to access `domain.com/buildzone_admin/test2` then see if this work

`$main->route('POST /test3', 'Test->post');` with `post` method just `var_dump(\Base::instance()->get('POST'))` to just see your app can catch `$_POST` via form.

->open POSTMAN, test with POST method, and body is `form-data` format with `a1`, `a2` post field then send request to `domain.com/buildzone_admin/test3`

To test other methods (like "PATCH"), make sure that you read F3 documentation. You may try with \Base::instance->get('BODY') with `Content-Type: application/json` header,
etc.

Hope this help!

Comment: Yes Sir buildzone_admin is subfolder of public_html.  and htaccess file is located inside buildzone_admin folder and index.php file is also there.          I have Changed Rewritebase as per your instruction and also check simple $main->route('GET /test1', function() {echo "test with function worked";}).  But it's not working, also test1 is not giving result. same 404 Error.

Comment: :D Change your index file to run a F3 Hello Word project: `<?php $main = require __DIR__ . '/lib/base.php'; $main->route('GET /hello-word', function() {echo "Hello World";}); $main->run();` If you can not see this works even keeping your .htaccess file or mine, try to setup your project locally and make sure your lib is fine. `test1` I said above is a very begining route, It should works even others work or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. You've only defined one (GET) route, so if you try to load any other route you will get a 404. It's working exactly as you defined it.
2. I recommend that you use lambda functions to define your routes like this:

```php
$main->route('GET /[route]/@arg', function($main,$params) use (&$[classname]) {
  $arg = $params['arg'];
  // do something
  echo \Template::instance()->render("template_file");
});
```

3. F3::set no longer works. rather use

```php
$main->set();
```

4. you can also use this syntax:

```php
$main = \Base::instance();
```

5. each route must be defined, such as:

```php
$main->route('GET /show/@arg', function($main,$params) use (&$[classname]) {
});

$main->route('GET /list/@arg', function($main,$params) use (&$[classname]) {
});
```